# Cannot access variable out of its scope

Tags: java, android, variables, null

When I try to print longitude value at the line `log("11111111", longitude);` , it works well and it shows me the value.  However, when I try to print it at `log.e(22222222", longitude);` I get a `NullPointerException`.

I know i got null pointer exception cause log.e("2222222", longitude) called before addOnCompleteListner.
but what i should do to wait the addOnCompleteListner till finish and then access the value

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.karem.currentlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

class GetMyCoordinate extends Application {

    Context context;

    GetMyCoordinate(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    String longitude;

    String getDeviceLocation() {

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

        try {

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        longitude = String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude());
                        Log.e("1111111111", longitude);

                    }
                }
            });

            Log.e("22222222", longitude);


        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        }
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Typical nullpointer exception. longitude is NULL because it's not initialized in `22222222`. Why? It's because onComplete is called async. The log (222222222) is called BEFORE addOnCompleteListener finishes.

Comment: @ZUNJAE ok.. but how to access the value also in return it print null.. so what i should do

Comment: while(! location.isComplete()){ sleep(100);} ..basically when Task has two method isComplete() -> called if task is complete (whether successful completion or faailure) and isSuccessful() -> on succcessfull completion. Please refer the docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not what you think it is.  The `longitude` variable is *in scope* (not "scoop"!) in both places.

The actual problem is that in the statement:

```
    log.e(22222222", longitude);
```

you are accessing the variable `longitude` before it has been initialized.  The initialization is done when the `onComplete` method is called.  That happens when the `Task` referred to by `location` gets completed.

(There should be another clue.  If you look at the logs, you will probably see that the "22222222" log message appears *before* the "11111111" log message.)

Comment: ok.. i understand now... .forget log.e("2222222", longitude) ...but when i try to access the method from another activity it also return null

Answer (score 0):

The listener functions are async in nature so anything you define or assign is valid in async functions scope. So if you try to access it out of its scope you get the value that is in that scope. As you just declared "longitude" it's value is Null so you get null pointer exception. if you initialised it to some value say "x" then you get x printed from Log statement having 2222222 as 1st argument.

Hope it clears your doubt

Comment: ok... i understand why i got that error ... but how to access that value from out of scope

Comment: You can make a function and pass longitude as parameter and call that function inside addOnCompleteListener. there you can use both class variables and variables that you pass to function. But remember that when you come to main thread that value not exist. If you want that value in main thread you need to wait until that async task finish and value get assigned to longitude and then call your second Log statement

Comment: thanks.. but forget log("222222",longitude).. i now need to return longitude to return the value not null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in Thread switching its not the case of out of Scope as mentioned above by **Stephen C**. What happens is that when your code enters the try{} block you have transferred the control to your **(FusedLocationProviderClient and added a listener)** till the response comes for your location from a background thread.Your caller thread cannot wait for it. So, it actually goes on to print the log.e("22222222", longitude)(when the response has't arrived) and that's why the null value case arises.

Comment: ok.. what should i do to wait addOnCompleteListner add return the value after it finishes

Comment: As I Can see that you have written your code in the Application class so if you would make you main thread wait you might get an ANR. So the best way would be to use an interface and get the call back in the class required ,but because this code of yours is in the Application class what you can do is the that u can create a method to get the value of the longitude in the class u require the longitude.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this can be easily achieved with an interface.

1 - First define an interface

```
public interface ILocationReceived {

onLocationRecieved(String longitude);

}
```

2 - Pass that interface to the method

```
 public void getDeviceLocation(ILocationRecieved locationRecieved) {

}
```

3 - In you Async method pass the received location

```
locationRecieved.onLocationRecieved(longitude);
```

4 - On implementing the method simply recieve the longitude.

```
new GetMyCoordinate().getDeviceLocation( longitude -> 
// here you get your longitude from the async method.
// use it as you need
print (longitude)
```

);

**NOTE** : Wrote this without any ide so it might contain some syntax error.